# How should I design full screen win forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm start to working with win forms and I have a question. Let's assume that I want to create app that only display in full screen - how I should design this application ? I mean how to design this application to be sure that on all screen size this full size app will look the same? Which size of win forms I should set in Visual Studio to start project full screen apps ?

I hope you will get it what I'm asking for!

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all answer! I know that I can use WindowState properties but the merits was different - set up WindowState to maximized not affect to form size in Form1.cs [Design] in VS so I cannot see how this app will look like after resize to full screen (and it's probably not possible to see winform full screen size in VS designer ? writing VS designer I meant: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/364272/01.png ;). I try to make it simpler - I have window like that: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22077262/AA.JPG and size of this window is 700x480 - I want to have the same proportion after apps go to full screen - I notice something about Anchor - can that property provide me what I want ? :) I allowed myself a little experiment to use Anchor and I see some problem like overlapping: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22077262/BA.JPG - Is this effect of misuse that property or just we need to "help" anchor in programmatic way ? Sorry for long text :)

Comment: Set your winforms startup mode to Maximized.

Comment: You need to use `Anchor` property to keep the look the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Goto Properties:**

**Windowstate:**

```
Windowstate: Maximized
```

**[OR]:[Form_Load]:**

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Anchor` and `Dock` not fully solved my problem but I found `TableLayoutPanel`and this control with two properties mentioned before seems to solve my problem - thanks all ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

you can write window state in your load function...

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of your form that named "`WindowState`" set value of this property to "`Maximized`"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WindowState` property to make the window always fit the entire screen and you can use the `Anchor` property to keep the controls on the right places, even when the actual size differs on different systems.

More on the `Anchor` property can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte(v=vs.110).aspx